# Edit weaviate modules once it's running on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, weaviate

I have a Weaviate instance running on EC2. Usually, when using Weaviate I'm going to spin it up with a `docker-compose.yml` file, so all the modules I need can be configured by that. However, since Weaviate is already running on AWS, how would I add/change the modules in use? I want to add `text2vec-transformers`.

I can stop the instance, but I would prefer not to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Duda from Weaviate here :)

As you are using docker compose, you can edit your docker-compose.yml file and add the modules you want as an environment variable.

Here we have more information about it:
https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/configuration/modules#enable-modules

After the docker compose is properly defined, you can run

```
docker compose up -d
```

and your cluster will restart, now enabling the modules you configured.

Note that you can [only change some of the class definitions once it was created][1]. And the vectorizer, for example, isn't one of them.

Let me know if that helps :)
Thanks!
[1]: https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/config-refs/schema#mutability

Comment: I'm configuring via the CloudFormation stack - when I try to add 'text2vec-transformers' I get an update failed error. Is this because I can't use the text2vec-transformers module when using the AWS CloudFormation template?

Comment: This is probably something in AWS CloudFormation side. In Weaviate, those modules are builtin. As long as you add the module to ENABLE_MODULES and restart Weaviate, it will load those modules up.